# Call componentDidMount() in React Component which is not an extended class of React.component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react component which I later render inside my index.js

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.jsx

```
import SomeComponent from "./Components/SomeComponent ";

function App() {
    return <SomeComponent />
}

export default App;
```

SomeComponent.jsx (random name of component just for the example)

```
function SomeComponent() {

  //some code

  return ...

}

export default SomeComponent;
```

**The problem** is that I see a lot of people using

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount()
  //some code

  render() {
    return ...
  }
}
```

And I want to use that "componentDidMount()" that I see in a lot of code examples, but in my way of doing things, it seems to don't be possible.

But... it is possible? or there is another similar method that can I use?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to look into [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Seems that it should work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the functional components, from `React 16.8,` we have ***React Hooks***. And we can use `useEffect()` Hook to simulate what `componentDidMount()` does in a class based component. However, You will need to pass second argument as state value to the `useEffect()`, only then it behaves like `componentDidMount()` whenever the state value gets modified.

Something like this:

```
const [stateValue,useStateValue] = useState("enjoy");

useEffect(()=>{
 // ... Your code
},[stateValue]);
```